# How to combine images?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

WP7 application.
I have some images (that I get from some URIs on the internet) and I want to combine them (one on top of the other, the second at a certain x and y on top on the first). Can this be done in WP7? What library should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just place two Images in a Canvas:

```
<Canvas>
    <Image Source="uri1" Canvas.Top="10" Canvas.Left="20"/>
    <Image Source="uri2" Canvas.Top="30" Canvas.Left="40"/>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: No problem! another way is to use a Grid and set margins on the images